# Show 2 labels in FlatList React Native

Tags: react-native

I'm trying to render a flatlist that has 2 labels. I have done few options but nothing happened.
I want to show Title & Serial as Title & subtitle in each Item. If there is a solution really appreciated

Code:

```
const DATA = [
    {
      id: 'bd7acbea-c1b1-46c2-aed5-3ad53abb28ba',
      title: 'First Item',
      Serial: '1254'
    },
    {
      id: '3ac68afc-c605-48d3-a4f8-fbd91aa97f63',
      title: 'Second Items',
      Serial: '5678'
    },
    {
      id: '58694a0f-3da1-471f-bd96-145571e29d72',
      title: 'Third Item',
      Serial: 'XXoX'
    },
  ];

  const Item = ({ title, Serial }) => (
      
    <TouchableOpacity style={styles.ttListButton}>
    <View style={styles.TTitem}>
      <Text style={styles.title}>{title}</Text>
      <Text style={styles.title}>{Serial}</Text>
    </View>
    </TouchableOpacity>
  );



 render() {
        const renderItem = ({ item }) => (
            <Item title={item.title} />
          );
    return(
    
<View style={{backgroundColor: '#fff'}}>
<FlatList
data={DATA}
renderItem={renderItem}
keyExtractor={item => item.id}
/>
</View>
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is a typo in ({ title, Seria })
should be ({ title, Serial })

```html
const renderItem = ({ item }) => (
            <Item title={item.title} Serial={item.Serial} />
          );
```

Comment: I have corrected but the issue still there